# Langchain's AzureOpenAI error: Resource not found

Tags: azure, openai-api, langchain

I’m trying to use LangChain’s AzureOpenAI as below but getting this error.
Do you know how can I fix this?

`openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Resource not found`

```
# Import Azure OpenAI
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
import openai
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://XXXXXX-openai.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2022-12-01"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    openai_api_type="azure",
    deployment_name="text-davinci-003", 
    model_name="text-davinci-003") 

print(llm("hi"))
```

Use Azure OpenAI with LangChain framework

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was removing the import of `openai` when using the `langchain.llms.AzureOpenAI` module.

In you example, try removing line 3 `import openai`

In my code, I also did not include `openai_api_type="azure"` since it is already set as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Switching this line from

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2023-03-15-preview"
```

to

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2022-12-01"
```

fixed the error for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below code with a sample Azure OpenAPI and it worked successfully.

**Code:-**

```py
# Import Azure OpenAI
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
import openai
import os

# os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "<open-api-key>"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2022-12-01"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    # openai_api_type="azure",
    deployment_name="text-davinci-003", 
    model_name="text-davinci-003") 

print(llm("hi"))
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Another output:-

[image]

Double check if  your OpenAPI key and ***Azure Open AI Endpoint*** that you have entered in the os.env code is missing any string or characters. Make sure the endpoint you are using for Azure is correct and not invalid.

> You can verify the endpoint by visiting :-
> ***Azure OpenAI Studio > Playground >  Code view or by visiting your OpenAI resource on azure in the Resource management section***
>
> Refer this Github MS document for the details mentioned above and run the code of
> this github repo:- [azure-docs/python.md at main ·
> MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs ·
> GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cognitive-services/openai/includes/python.md)

> Get the deployment model from the model you deployed while creating
> the resource- Refer  this MS document here-
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/create-resource?pivots=web-portal Make sure the model name is correct as that also causes resource not found error like below:-
> **Error:-**

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: The model `text-davin-043` does not exist
```

[image]

> Additionally check if there's any space or character after your api
> base key try deleting it and run the code again and refer other
> solutions mentioned in this MS forum regarding the same error code :-
>
> [Open AI error: "InvalidRequestError: Resource not found". Please help
> to fix. - Microsoft
> Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187169/open-ai-error-invalidrequesterror-resource-not-fou?orderby=helpful)

Answer (score 0):

As devon [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76059596/2084960), just remove the openai import

Answer (score 0):

Need to restart OS when set env in windows **important**